# Laravel AJAX Request into route api Vue error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I am trying to make an ajax request using Vue to get data from an API route using the auth middleware to get recently created issues. I was able to get it to work without checking auth however i need it to check auth and also get the Users id that is creating the request. I currently have this.
My view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
<script src="/public/js/adminApp.js"></script>
<template id="messages-template">
  <div>
    <ul class="menu" v-for="messages in list">
      <li><!-- start message -->
        <a href="#">
          <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left: 9px;margin-right: 9px;">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
          <h4>@{{ messages && messages.name }}
            <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
          </h4>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/messages.js">
</script>
```

My api.php route:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
  Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
    return App\issue::latest()->get();
  });
});
```

My messages.js vue script:

```
Vue.component('messages', {
  template: '#messages-template',
  data: function (){
  return {
    list:[]
  };},
  created (){
    $.getJSON('/api/test', function(messages){
      this.list = messages;
    }.bind(this))
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#messagesArea'
});
```

The error message i get currently is 401 and the route is giving back : `{"error":"Unauthenticated."}`

Comment: You specified the `auth:api` middleware for the group that this route belongs to. It's probably expecting some sort of token with the request. You didn't provide one, so it's unable to authenticate.

Comment: I thought that the: $.ajaxSetup which should get the token from the meta would work because that is what i read else where @ZacBrown

Comment: Oh, yea. Sorry. Didn't catch that. I think @asemahle's answer below is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written:

```
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

This looks for a `<meta>` element, whose name is `csrf-token`, and parses out the `content`. So, for it to work, you need to add that `meta` tag to the document head. Try this:

```
<meta id="token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: I have just added that in and im still getting 401 unauthroized error @asemahle

Comment: Can you verify that `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` is working? Try running it in the console. It should print the value of the csrf token.

Comment: Hm... that seems to be working.  If the csrf-token is being set, then I'm not sure what the problem is. You could look at the request in developer tools. In chrome, under the network tab, find the call to `/api/test` and verify that it either has a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in the header, or a `XSRF-TOKEN` as a request cookie.

Comment: all i see is [this](http://imgur.com/a/xqBIf) It looks like there is the token in COOKIE

Comment: @RPSystems Try diving into the auth middleware and add print statements where laravel is verifying the csrf headers to see if the server gets them.